Find reserved capacity in AWS reserved instances
I'm using reserved instances. I want to find out how much capacity remains after launching the instance. in the reserve instance, I can't see how many instances are attached, and how much capacity is available. With only billing we know the usage only, but which reserved instance is it using?
Ex: I have created reserve instances with the instance count 5, and I created 2 on-demand instances. How do I know the remaining capacity?
If I created 2 reserved instances, with the same type and platform, when I launch on-demand instances with the same type and platform. in which reserved instance it will attach.
I'm using python code to get those details, but I can't. Please help.

It is not possible to 'launch' a Reserved Instance.
Rather, Reserved Instances are a billing discount. If you are running On-Demand EC2 instances that match the configuration of Reserved Instances you have purchased, then you will be billed at the Reserved Instance price instead of the normal On-Demand price for the instance.
Let's say you bought one Reserved Instance for a particular EC2 configuration, but you launched two such instances. One would be charged at the Reserved Instance rate and the other would be charged at the normal On-Demand rate.
The instance charged at the Reserved Instance price cannot be identified, because it isn't one particular instance. It is merely a pricing discount for one instance. As an example, let's say you terminated one of those EC2 instances. The remaining instance would be charged at the Reserved Instance price regardless of which instance was terminated.

i need more clarification on this.

can I create multiple reserved instances with the same instance type and platform?
how can I get how many on-demand instances are attached to the particular reserved instance?
example: i created 2 reserved instances with t2.medium and Linux/Unix, with instance count is 5, then i created 4 on-demand instances with the same config, now how can I get which on-demand instance is attached to which reserved instance?
after attaching the on-demand instance to the reserved instance, how can I get the remaining capacity in a reserved instance?


No, I don't think you can obtain it. Reserved Instances are a billing discount, not an attribute of the instance. Also, the instances that qualify for the Reserved Instance discount might change minute-by-minute depending on what instances have been launched/terminated. Apparently you might be able to view it via the console. See: How to check which instance is reserved in AWS?
